# Does Mimasa philosophy believe in Ithihasa and Puranas?

Tags: scripture, belief, purva-mimamsa

Though various devatas and gods are mentioned in Karma Kanda of Vedas, Mimasa doubts their existence. But there are many Puranic characters mentioned in Samhitas. Even Brahmanas of Vedas contain Ithihas and Puranic legends. How Mimamsa explain this?

Comment: They think it is entirely allegorical.

Comment: I would say Devas do exist. If you renounce the worldly enjoyments and sit for tapasya for God realization, at first, you will face lot of Tests from him as mentioned in our Puranas.

Comment: @Ikshvaku means metaphorical? So they don't believe in Manvantaras, Kalpas, Yugas etc? If they don't believe in Yuga cycle, how can they establish the eternity of Vedas.

Comment: Itihāsa texts come under smr̥ti. Please check Mīmāṁsā sūtras, adhyāya 1, pada 3. That portion does discuss about the authority and reliance of smr̥ti texts in comparison to śruti.
I am sharing that portion from Tantravārttika which is Kumārila's commentary on Śabara bhāṣya on Mīmāṁsā sūṭras. 
https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.282920/page/n273/mode/2up?view=theater

Answer (score 2):

See Mimamsa does not say that the Devas do not exist. This is a false interpretation of the Sutras. They do not comment much about the Devas or the Supreme Isvara. Their main focus has always been the Yajna Dharma.

But Mimamsa scholars who have written commentary on the Vedas have accepted Puranas and Itihasas. For example, take Sayanacaraya, he commented on all 4 Vedas. He has quoted Puranas at times to support the Tripura Vadha mentioned in Taittirya Samhita and Rg Veda Samhita.
He has quoted Puranas for supporting the story of Lord Rudra being the father of the Maruts. He uses the Puranic references for the five faces of Lord Siva. In his very first Mangalacaranam, he writes a Stuti for Mother Sarasvati, Ganesa and the Supreme Mahadeva. This shows that he did accept the Puranas and Itihasas. But he calls them mere stories and not our history.
These are the words of Sayanacaraya:

**यस्य निःश्वसितं वेदा यो वेदेभ्योऽखिलं जगत्‌ । निर्ममे तमहं वन्दे विद्यातीयमेश्वरम्‌ ॥**

> The Vedas are the breath of Him, and from the Vedas, the entire
> universe is created. I offer my obeisances to Mahesvara, who created
> the universe.

---

Another great Mimamsa scholar, Sri Bhatta Bhaskaracarya who commented on the Taittiriya Samhita, Taittiriya Brahmana and the Taittiriya Aranyaka also accepts the Itihasas and Puranas. He predates Sayanacaraya and his commentary on the Yajur Veda is considered greater than that of Sayanacarya. He also states that:

**इतिहासपुरणाज्ञ: पदवाक्यप्रमाणवित् । अर्थोपकारवेदी च वेदार्थम् ज्ञातुमर्हति ॥**

> He who knows the Itihasas, and Puranas and who is well-versed in the
> proofs of meanings and sentences, a person who is aware of the
> benefits of these should understand the Vedas.

He also was a devotee of Lord Siva, this again shows that Mimamsakas did not reject the Itihasas and Puranas

**ईशानः सर्वविद्यानां भूतानामीश्वरः परः । पुनातु सर्वदा चास्मान्‌ शब्दब्रह्मतनुः शिवः ॥**

> Isana is the Lord of all knowledge and the Supreme Lord of all living
> entities. May Lord Śiva, whose body is the Vedas, always purify us.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sāyaṇa's verse which you cited only praises the Vedas and doesn't mention smr̥ti or itihāsa. 
Also, could you please share the name of the works and the verse numbers of the verses/excerpts you cited? Also, where does it say that Bhaṭṭa Bhāskara Miśra was a Mīmāṁsaka? I am not sure about that.  As for Sāyaṇa being a  Mīmāṁsaka or not is a matter of debate, it's not certain, if he was one even though *Galewicz* states so in his research. There is no commentary of Sāyaṇa or Bhaṭṭa Bhāskara on the Mīmāṁsā sutras nor any text which shows their adherence to Jaimini or those sūtras.

Comment: If there is a mention of both of them being Mīmāṁsakas in any of the old texts, please share where it is so. 
It's strange that you don't offer the views of Jaimini, Kumārila, Prabhākara or Śabara at all on this topic, after all Pūrva Mīmāṁsā sūtras and its commentaries are the main text. Mīmāṁsā sūtras do discuss on smr̥ti, its authority and reliance in adhyāya 1, pada 3.

Comment: @Bingming Jaimini, himself does not mention anything about Brahma or Isvara, he is only focused on the rituals completely.

Comment: @Bingming the verses are from Mangalacarnam which is the very first page of the Bhasyas before starting the commentary on the Suktas.

Comment: @Bingming both Sayana and Bhatta Bhaskaracarya are Mimamsakas, Sayana himself follows the Jaimini Sutras in his Bhasyas, please read them. Kumarila and others wrote their commentaries way later and are no authority on the Sutras.

Comment: I know about Jaimini, but you didn't cite any proper reason still for saying that Sāyaṇa and Bhaṭṭa Bhāskara are Mīmāṁsakas. Also, Śabara exited in the early CE way before Sāyaṇa. And Kumārila existed before Sāyaṇa. You may not know that Sāyaṇa comes after Śaṅkara, he is from around 13th-14th century. On the other hand, Śabara existed in early CE and Kumārila in the eight century CE.

Comment: So, you got 1 fact wrong, that Sāyaṇa existed before Śabara, Kumārila and others. 
And then you also didn't provide any proper source for Sāyaṇa and Bhaṭṭa Bhāskara being Mīmāṁsakas. Where does it say they are? Also, let's take for granted they are Mīmāṁsakas, why is their name not listed among the commentators of  Mīmāṁsā sūtra, no where do Kumārila, Śabara, or any later commentators mention them in the commentaries. Please don't say that you are are saying they are Mīmāṁsakas on the basis of wikipedia.

Comment: Plus, you stated the views of Sāyaṇa and Bhaṭṭa Bhāskara but why is it lacking any reference to the Mīmāṁsā sūtra. Provide the proper verse numbers from the sūtras to support your point. Actually, if you want to check  adhyāya 1, pada 3 in the Mīmāṁsā sūtras discusses about the authority of smr̥ti texts. But they are not the same in content with what views you stated above.

Comment: I can agree they might be Mīmāṁsakas, but for that you need to cite any portion from their bhāṣyas to show that they actually adhere to Jaimini's sūtras. Or need to show a Mīmāṁsā text which mentions them or follows their commentary. If they really are Mīmāṁsakas, it's pretty easy to show that.

Comment: You really have to just go and read theor Bhāṣya. The very introduction that they give to their Bhāṣya clears it all of. Commentaries matter not to me. There is a reason Mūla Sūtra exist.

Comment: @Soorya S A Can you share the source of the last sloka please?

Comment: @SanatanaDhara it's the Maṅgalam of Taittirīya Saṃhitā by Śrī Bhatta Bhaskarācārya. You will get it on archives

Comment: @Soorya S found it thank you.